# Configuring osTicket to fetch mail from an email account

Tags: web-hosting, customer-service, ticket-system

I'm trying to use osTicket to implement a ticketing system but I'm not able to fetch the mails from an email account even after configuring the host, port, user name and password.

Comment: I use OSTicket on several sites, and have no problem fetching mail with it.

To start we are going to need to know why you think it is not working. Does an error message come up at all, or is it just not fetching mail without showing an error?

Also, what is the domain of the e-mail address you are trying to fetch mail from? Some e-mail addresses, like Gmail and any other Google Apps e-mail addresses, need some additional settings to work properly.

Comment: @SherwinFlight I did not setup a cron job,i think how can i do it

Comment: im using cpanel hosting

Comment: Are you asking how to set up a cron job in cPanel, or are you asking for the specific osticket cron settings?

Comment: specific osticket cron settings for cron.php

Answer (score 1):

To make the mail fetch work you need to be running thr cron.php file as frequently as you need to poll the mail server.

**Cron**
`*/5 * * * * nobody /path/to/php /path/to/api/cron.php`

**Windows Scheduled Tasks**
Add `"c:\php\bin\php.exe c:\website\osticket\api\cron.php"` to the Windows scheduled tasks pane.

Note that the cron.php file has restrictions in place to ensure that it is triggered by the server and not a remote browser connection or remote virtual scheduled tasks provider.

http://osticket.com/wiki/POP3/IMAP_Setting_Guide#Recurring_tasks_scheduler_.28Cron_Job.29